How to output only CMD column of docker top <container>?
docker top <c_name> shows 8 columns. Is there a way to show only CMD column by Docker instruments?

You can use awk to filter out CMD. Try this.
docker top <container id> | awk NR>1 '{print $8}'


I have tried awk but with no NR>1 it prints only php-fpm: in my case and don't print its ending.
With NR>1 it prints error:
awk: fatal: cannot open file {print $8}' for reading: No such file or directory`

please share the sample data, I will update the command. Need some more information on your requirement.

Hm.. that way do what I want but has empty tabs at the start
awk '{$1=$2=$3=$4=$5=$6=$7=""; print $0}' and looks ugly

UID                 PID                 PPID                C                   STIME               TTY                 TIME                CMD
The header line I have. other lines shows data according it. I cannot share the data. I need only data below CMD header

I've made solution as separated answer.

According to the similar question at stackoverflow:
docker top <container_name> | awk '{$1=$2=$3=$4=$5=$6=$7=""; print $0}' | sed 's/^\s*//g'

